# PHP Random Number Generator Using Array and substr

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a simple lottery number generator for my own amusement. I have to pick six numbers between 1 & 49, obviously without repeats.

I have tried using the `mt_rand` feature for six different variables then echoing them in order, but I guess there is the possibility of repeated numbers. So now I'm trying to get the following to work.

```
<?php 
$randomString = substr(shuffle("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49"), 0, 6); echo $randomString; 
?>
```

I know that substr is for strings and not arrays but I can't find the alternative.

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get 6 numbers from the array:

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 49);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 6);
print_r($numbers);
?>
```

Comment: I bet `array_rand()` is going to be more efficient.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php  Not that it matters for such a small array.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_rand`](http://php.net/array-rand) is basically designed for this, but keep in mind that it returns the *keys*, not the values.

So try this:

```
$numbers = array_rand(array_flip(range(1,49)),6);
var_dump($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better practice would be to just get 6 different random numbers from 1 to 49

```
numbers = array();
for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
    do{
        pick = rand(1,49);
    }while (in_array(pick, numbers));
    numbers[] = pick;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and the [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function some code below.

---

```
function num_rand($min, $max, $val) {
   $range = range($min, $max);
   shuffle($range);
   $result = array_slice($range, 0, $val);

      foreach($result as $number) {
         $number_string .= $number . ', ';
      }

   return rtrim($number_string, ', ');
}


echo num_rand('1', '49', '6');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also random 6 numbers and check if there is no repetition like this:

```
<?php
srand();
$TOTAL = 6;
$MAX = 46;
$MIN = 1;

$numbers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $TOTAL; $i++) {
do {
    $new_number = rand($MIN,$MAX);
}
while(in_array($new_number, $numbers));

echo $new_number . "<br>";
}
?>
```

For me this is the most straightforward solution but I don't know if it's the best one.